# Should I declare Message object as class member?

Tags: android

I have a few classes that frequently communicate with a service. Message are sent using

```
private void sendMessage(int what)
{
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, what);
    try
    {
        mServerMessenger.send(msg);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {

    }
}
```

My question is

- Should I declare a class member `Message mMessage` instead of declaring it locally.
- If declare as a class member should I use the `Message constructor`
  or use `Message.obtain`.
- As class member do I need to call `recycle` in `onDestroy` if using
  `Message.obtain`.

So far I do not experience any memory problem, but I would like to use the system resource as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my 2c on this:

> 1) Should I declare a class member Message mMessage instead of
>   declaring it locally.

I would like to have a class member so that JVM don't have to create entry for local variable at each method call..

> 2) If declare as a class member should I use the Message constructor or
>   use Message.obtain.

Always use `obtain()` since it use object pooling..

> 3) As class member do I need to call recycle in `onDestroy` if using
>   Message.obtain.

You don't need to call recycle just `nullify` the `class variable`.

you can have a look at the [`Message.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/Message.java) source for more info..

I would also go through it and update the post if I found anything more..

EDIT1:

Again I would request you to check the source code.. The `recycle()` method should be called if you want to return the object to the `global object pool`.. You should not use the object after calling the recycle method.. Copying the method (ICS) for quick reference:

```
/**
 * Return a Message instance to the global pool.  You MUST NOT touch
 * the Message after calling this function -- it has effectively been
 * freed.
 */
public void recycle() {
    clearForRecycle();

    synchronized (sPoolSync) {
        if (sPoolSize < MAX_POOL_SIZE) {
            next = sPool;
            sPool = this;
            sPoolSize++;
        }
    }
}
```

The instance would be available for you to use as long as you don't call 'recyle()'. So in case it would be good practice to call `recycle()` before calling the `obtain()` method in your code.. and in the `onDestroy()` call `recycle()` and `nullify` the object..

Comment: I read the document but it is not clear. For example, obtain() is from a global pool but if I use a constructor then is it also pull out from the global pool. Is there a guarantee that the message exists as long as my class exist if using obtain()? In what situation should one call recycle()?

Comment: +1 for source code link. The pool size is only 10, so if I keep it for a life time of my classes which is all the time, I may use 5 of them. So I do not know if this is a good idea. There will be more garbage collection but maybe my service will be less likely to be killed by the system.

Comment: if you call `recycle()` before calling `obtain()` then most of the time you may end up using the recycled object. and it is always good to avoid creating new object..

Comment: I think if I declared as a class member I should use the constructor, that way I do not deplete the global pool. If I used obtain(), then at any time the global pool would only have 5 left for the entire system.

Comment: Even the constructor doc says that `obtain()` should be used to get the instance.. and its hard to predict how the system is using the `Message` class.. So if I go by the design of the `Message` class I would like to use `obtain()` to get the instance and call `recycle()` when I am done with the object..

Comment: The thing is my classes is running all the times, so if I declared as a class member then unless my service is killed by the system, the app would hold at least 3 messages from the pool. Other apps and the system only has 7 or less to use.

Comment: So if we forget about drawbacks of local variable creation inside the method.. Then you can create local variable and call `obtain()` each time you need to call service, and in the service whenever you are done with the `Message` object just call the `recycle()` on it so that it would be returned to the pool.. This way you would not hold any un-necessary reference to the `Message object`..